# Have same style for article and inproceedings in biblatex numeric style

Tags: biblatex, biber

In the numeric style, the article and inproceedings have different format for year. I need them to be in the same format for a non-academic document. I managed to add parenthesis around the year, remove "in:" from proceedings, but I need to also remove the dot before the year in the inproceedings references. I only need author, title, booktitle (or journal), and year fields. I looked up many questions here, but I couldn't find any for this. Here is what I have so far with example references:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,maxbibnames=99,sorting=ydnt,giveninits=true,style=numeric,autocite=plain]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{wombat2016,
    author   = {Walther Wombat and Klaus Koala},
    title    = {The true meaning of 42},
    journal  = {Journal of modern skepticism},
    year     = {2016},
}
@inproceedings{holleis2010,
    author    = {Holleis, Paul and Wagner, Matthias and Koolwaaij, Johan},
    title     = {Studying mobile context-aware social services in the wild},
    booktitle = {Proc. of the 6th Nordic Conf. on Human-Computer Interaction},
    year      = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{wombat2016,holleis2010}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of references]